# How to change timeout for HttpSend activity?

Tags: 2013, workflow, workflow-activity

I found myself in a situation when workflow send http request to a service and should take response from it. But the service works for a long time. So as a result I receive "Suspended" status in the workflow due to short timeout.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found timeout setting in `WFResourceManagementDB` database, `WorkflowServiceConfig` table (`WorkflowServiceMaxHttpResponseTime` value).

Increasing the value resolved my issue.

Comment: Please do not modify directly SP databases. You will save yourself a lot of trouble in the future.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to set the configuration value via powershell (s. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680843(v=azure.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680843%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)).

To set the timeout to 2 min open Worflow Manager Powershell and use

```
Set-WFServiceConfiguration -ServiceUri *YourURI* -Name WorkflowServiceMaxHttpResponseTime -Value 00:02:00
```

See the Warning on MSDN Page about possible fallbacks of an increased timeout.