# SharePoint Designer Workflow 2013 executes "call http request" action and is retrying 4 times

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow. In this workflow I have a "call http request" action. In this action I try to execute a PowerAutomate like in [this tutorial](https://ppmworks.com/triggering-microsoft-flow-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/). It looks like this "call http request" action has some timeout/retry mechanism. We see that if the Power Automate take allot of time to response (for example 10 minutes), SharePoint Designer 2013 will do a retry on the "call http request" action. So the Power Automate will run again. And we see that SharePoint Designer 2013 is executed this action the first time, and then 4 retry's. Who knows about this behaviour? Is there some blog or documentation about this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems that the workflow waited too long for the response, and automatically requested the Rest again.

Try to reset some attributes related to the workflow manager's HTTP request, such as

[WorkflowServiceMaxHttpResponseTime, WorkflowServiceMaxHttpRetryDelay](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/workflow-manager/jj680843(v=azure.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Similar issues:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/168206/sharepoint-workflow-triggers-multiple-calls-to-the.html

[How to change timeout for HttpSend activity?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95614/how-to-change-timeout-for-httpsend-activity)

Comment: We are using SharePoint Online. Is your solution compatible with SharePoint Online or only SharePoint onpremises?

Comment: If you have workflow server , it will work.

Comment: SharePoint Online dont have a workflow server.